# Django get related object in one-to-one relationship without knowing the related model

Tags: django, django-models, one-to-one

How do I get the related object of a model in this case:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    pass

class ModelB(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(ModelA, related_name='b_object', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ModelC(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(ModelA, related_name='c_object', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I know that if I do:

```
ModelA.b_object # returns related b object
ModelA.c_object # returns related c object
```

But since this is a one to one relationship, a particular instance of ModelA will only be related to a single instance of one of those models, so:

**Is there a general way to get the related object without knowing if the related object is from one model or the other?**

Something like: `ModelA.get_related_object`

Does Django provide this functionality? Should I build a custom method for this and how?

Use case example (for clarity): in a DetailView template for ModelA, get the related object for that instance.

Comment: By your definition object A could be related to a B object and a C object at the same time. Is this the behavior that you want?

Comment: Not at the same time, right?  And instance of A can be related to only one instance (of model B or C)

Comment: There's nothing stopping it. You'll have to use Django Model Constraints for that.

Comment: Isn't that what OneToOneField does?  Preventing from having a one-to-many relation?

Comment: Preventing from having a one-to-many relation with the related table. You can have as many relations as you want with other tables.